# I want to create a source file that calls a function without having to create an object

Tags: c++, static, header

Suppose I want mergesort.cpp that implements mergesort.  So in my .cpp file I have something like:

```
int * mergesort(int * a, int lo, int hi)
{
  //mergesort
}
```

and in the header mergesort.h, I would have:

```
public static int mergesort(int *, int, int);
```

Then in another sourcefile, say main.cpp where I included mergesort.h, I would like to call the function mergesort without having to create any instance of an object.

```
int a [10];
mergesort::mergesort(a,0,9);
```

Okay, but this doesn't work because I don't know the proper syntax, and I don't really know what terminology to use to ask the question, but hopefully it is clear.

Comment: There's no type to class an object of, please clarify. Is `mergesort` defined inside a `class` or `struct`?

Comment: Search the Web for non-member functions.

Comment: Please provide a SSCCE http://sscce.org/ the code sample does not provide enough information. Is `mergesort` part of a class, struct or namespace, if not then you need to drop the `mergesort::` and `public static`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put

```
int mergesort(int *, int, int);
```

in the header and then call

```
mergesort(a,0,9);
```

from your `main.cpp` and you will be fine.

I suppose that you come from a true object oriented language (such as Java) background, where everything needs to be an object. In C++ a standalone function is perfectly fine. There is also no need for the public and static keywords, since those pertain to classes.

I strongly recommend that you read a C or C++ book. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 1):

I think you're thinking in Java, not C++.  In the header you want, simply:

```
extern int *mergesort(int *, int int);
```

and in your main.cpp, you would simply call it as:

```
mergesort(a, 0, 9);
```

Comment: The `extern` is implicit for function declarations, unless I'm sorely mistaken. Any particular reason you include it?

Comment: It's not strictly necessary, agreed.  It is a habit I got into as a C programmer years back, to mirror declarations of external variables and objects.  Granted, global variables are bad style, but still fairly common in C code.  Also, `extern` on a templated function prevents instantiating redundant specializations, so another reason for the habit.

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need a static modifier in this instance.

```
//mergesort.h
#ifndef MERGESORT_H
#define MERGESORT_H
int* mergesort(int*, int, int);
#endif
```

And...

```
//mergesort.cpp
#include "mergesort.h"
int* mergesort(int * a, int lo, int hi)
{
   // do your thing
}
```

And later on:

```
// some other file
#include "mergesort.h"

int main()
{
    int a [10];
    mergesort(a,0,9);    
    return 0;
}
```